# Why is every derivation a vector?

Tags: differential-topology

We can see the vectors of the tangent space $T_pM$ to a smooth manifold as velocities of curves. This is [elaborated here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_as_velocities_of_curves).

Each velocity $\gamma'(0)$ corresponds to a derivation $D_{\gamma}(f) = (f \circ \gamma)'(0)$ as seen in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_derivations).

But why is every derivation also a velocity (vector)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you choose local coordinates, a basis for the derivations is $\left\{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\Big|_p,\dots, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\Big|_p\right\}$. Then there's an obvious curve with tangent vector $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p$.

Comment: Oh, I think I see this. Let $(x,U)$ be a chart near $p \in U$. Let $\gamma(t) = x(p) + t(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ be a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, $x^{-1} \circ \gamma$ is a curve in the manifold such that $(x^{-1} \circ \gamma)(0) = p$, and it has the required tangent vector.

Comment: Parfaitement. Très bien. :)

Comment: Haha. Thanks a lot for your help. +1 and accepted.